# can find the password it is asking for Gitlab

Tags: git, docker

I am trying to clone a project from my gitlab account to my laptop. I have an ssh key on my labtop and it has been added to my gitlab account. When i try to clone the project, it is asking me for the following password. Idk which password it is asking for. ssh key password, account password, or any other password. I am logged into docker through my terminal

This is what is coming up...

```
docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username (omarjandali): omarjandli
Password:
Login Succeeded

git clone git@107.170.239.166:alpha-testing/OpenTab.git opentab
Cloning into 'opentab' ...
git@107.170.239.166's password:
```

UPDATE:::

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/omar-jandali/OpenTab.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "gitlab"]
    url = git@107.170.192.132:root/testing.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gitlab/*
[remote "original"]
    url = git@107.170.239.166:root/OpenTab.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/original/*
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "opentab" directory open the ".git/config" file and note the [remote "origin"]'s url section. If the url has http:// or https:// try replacing it with ssh:// and ensure you have your SSH key configured properly on your system.

Comment: Well. the thing is that it was not asking me when i was pushing and pulling the gitlab repo on my computer. once i tried doing it on my laptop, is when it started asking for a password. I will update my question with the config file. I have a remote called original that has the current url of that i am trying to clone. does that mean anything....

Comment: it does not ask for password on pc but when i try to access it on my laptop i get an issue.... will replacing the origin make a different